# Apply style on insert into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a search by tags input box as seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/7nUAf/

Forgive the terrible styling as this is just a small component of a larger application and I've just added the styles needed to show my issue.

My search box is a `div` that has it's text inserted using Jquery as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.search-box').click(function () {
     $('.search-options').toggle();

 });

 $('.options').click(function () {

     var d = $('.search-box').html();
     console.log(d);
     var c = $(this).html();
     console.log(c);
     if (d != '') {
         $('.search-box').html(d + ', ' + c);
     } else {
         $('.search-box').html(c);
     }
     $('.search-options').hide();
 });
 $('#reset').click(function () {
     $('.search-box').html('');
 });
 });
```

where `.search-box` is the input div, `.options` are the clickable options from the drop down box `search-options`.

Currently, the text of each option is inserted into the search-box div. I need this to be styled dynamically while it enters the search box.

I tried something on the lines of:

```
  $('<span>').addClass('tag').append(
                    $('<span>').text(value).append('&nbsp;&nbsp;'),
                    $('<a>', {
                        href  : '#',
                        title : 'Removing tag',
                        text  : 'x'
                    });
```

where the `tag` class is defined in the style sheet to style the element to look like a tag,
but this doesn't work at all. Can someone help me out with how to achieve styling the input text to look like a tag from, say, Evernote notebooks?

Thanks!

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Comment: @BenM welp, I did try that. But this app has been already built and it tends to break whenever I try to bring in new libraries. I already tried Xoxco's tag input but it broke the entire app.

Comment: @Newtt "Broke" meaning it broke styles/layout or it entirely broke the application? If the former you probably had overlapping css classes. Just a thought!

Comment: @drew_w broke the entire application haha. If it were just css, then I'd have fixed it

Comment: @Newtt Thats a real bummer. Probably an indication that the application isn't well constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted your fiddle. Just wrap `c` in a span with a class (like you were trying to do in the second part of your post) and apply styles in css. I have just made the background red, but it should be easy enough to make it look like a tag like the ones in the drop down do.

http://jsfiddle.net/7nUAf/1/

JS:

```
 $('.options').click(function () {
     var d = $('.search-box').html();
     var c = $(this).html();
     $('.search-box').append('<span class="tag">'+c +'</span>');
     $('.search-options').hide();
 });
```

CSS:

```
.tag {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you are looking to do - there are lots of excellent plug ins already available that provide much "prettier" functionality and with much less work on your part. Some have already been suggested in the comments - I might suggest consider using ["chosen"](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#multiple-select). The syntax is amazingly simple. Just create a select box as follows:

```
<select id="test" multiple>
  <option>pdf</option>
  <option>document</option>
</select>
```

Then in your document ready function you simply need to call chosen plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').chosen({width: "80%"});
});
```

I put together an example that does this on JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7nUAf/3/. Once you get to the point that you have it working you can easily style the elements by inspecting what elements chosen is creating. For example the "li.search-choice" selector will allow you to style the selected items.

*In General* - even if you don't like this particular plug in, always consider running a search for existing items that do what you are looking for. In the case that these aren't perfect you can always improve them and provide that insight back to the community as a whole. In that way, everyone learns together.

Best of luck!